# Changing images using dataprocessors in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, dom, ckeditor

I am trying to alter HTML output from images in CKEditor, but I am having trouble iterating elements returned from the dataprocessor function.

HTML in the editor:

```
<p>Test</p>

<p><img alt="" class="align-left" height="170" src="http://example.local/assets/img/uploads/photo.jpg" width="161" />&nbsp;some text</p>
```

Dataprocessor:

```
htmlFilter.addRules( {
    elements : {
        $ : function( element ) {
            console.log(element.children);
            element.children.forEach(function(ele) {
                console.log(ele);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I wanted to simply find the image tag using something like `element.name == 'img'`, but only the `p`-tags are parsed. When I log `element.children` I see the `img` in the second paragraph:

[image]
However, when I iterate `element.children` using `element.children.forEach(function(ele) { console.log(ele); })` I get this instead of the `img` tag, with the `span` containing the `img`:

[image]

Does anyone know what's happening? How can I access the image tag?

I am using the enhances image plugin btw, though I don't think that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `img` instead of `$`. Whenever you switch to source mode or get data from the editor, you will get images go through that code.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function( evt ) {
            evt.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    img: function( el ) {
                        console.log( el );
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
    }
});
```